# Getting screen size return 0

Tags: android

I am trying to get the screen size on my emulator (API 7) with this code:

```
float scaledDensity = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

Now I try to use `scaledDensity`

with this code:

```
int width = (width / ((int) scaledDensity)) / 7;
```

and I get this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tomer.workoutlog2/com.example.workoutlog.SimpleCalendarViewActivity}: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
```

Full code:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;

        } else
            width = display.getWidth();

        float scaledDensity = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;

        width = (width / ((int) scaledDensity)) / 7;
```

On my real device I don't get this error. 
Maybe, is the problem  with the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

for API 7 you can use the following code, it is deprecated from API 13

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

scaledDensity() returns a float. Sure you are not accidentally doing a integer division with an float less than 1.0f?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
float scaleFactor = displaymetrics.density;
```

Comment: You can have the scaleFactor by this code:
 `float scaleFactor = displaymetrics.density;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```